# Downgrading postgis 3.0.1 to 2.4.4

Tags: macos, homebrew, postgis, downgrade

I tried searching for brew download formula for a spesific version of postgis, but could not find one.
I tried running following

`ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.4.4";`

It gives following error

`ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no update path from version "3.0.1" to version "2.4.4" SQL state: 22023`

Any other possible way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know another way. As far as I know you have only the possibilities that are listed in the PostGIS-Folder of your Postgres-installation

- e.g. C:\apps\PostgreSQL\13\share\extension

In my case with PostGIS 3.1.1 there are only Upgrade and no downgrade-options:

- postgis--2.0.0--3.1.1.sql
- postgis--2.0.1--3.1.1.sql
- postgis--2.0.2--3.1.1.sql
- ...
- postgis--3.1.0--3.1.1.sql